# powershell pipeline isn't passed via invoke-expression

Tags: powershell, pipeline, invoke

powershell newbie here.  I'm trying to invoke another script from my current script, but the '$_' never makes it through.

```
invoke-expression "$cleanScript -pattern $ageDir -days2keep $ageDays | ? {$_.keep -eq $false}"

keep : The term '.keep' is not recognized as the name of
At line:1 char:112
+ ... :\backup\archive\*.zip -days2keep 14
+
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.keep:Strin
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is regarded - quite correctly - as dangerous. it otta be used only when _needed_. so ... what are you trying to achieve that caused you to look into `Invoke-Expression`? lookee ... Invoke-Expression considered harmful | PowerShell Team Blog — https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/

Comment: Try rewrite the following way: `invoke-expression "$cleanScript -pattern $ageDir -days2keep $ageDays | ? {\`$_.keep -eq \`$false}"`. Note the backticks before `$_.keep` and `$false`.

Comment: Would this be better -   & $cleanScript -pattern $ageDir -days2keep $ageDays | ? {$_.keep -eq `$false}